# Fastest way to calculate minimum distance from a large set of locations to facilties in R/sf

Tags: r, tidyverse, geospatial, distance, r-sf

I have two CSV files containing the coordinates of locations (11 million rows with three columns : "lid", "lat", "lon") and facilities (50k rows columns "fid", "lat", "lon"). For each location, I need to calculate the minimum distance to the nearest facility.

I know how to do this using "st_distance" in R. However, "st_distance" is taking ages because it first calculates the full matrix of distances and the two files are pretty large. I have tried breaking the location files intro smaller groups and use "future_map" across 3 cores, it is taking a lot more time than I expected. Is there a way to speed up the process?

Comment: `sf::st_nearest_feature()` might help. Otherwise, do a full join of your two sets, so every location is joined to every facility. Calculate the distance between each pair using `geodist`, then pick the minimum distance for each location. I recommend using `data.table` for all this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using st_buffer first? This would limit the amount of locations you would need to search to find the closest location. For example start with a radius of 10 miles and see if that captures all of the data. If that doesn't work maybe try the findNeighbors() function. See documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fractal/versions/2.0-4/topics/findNeighbors

In the future it would also be good if you provided a sample of your data.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not post the data because it is confidential.

Comment: If your data is confidential you should make up a small example that you _can_ post online. Questions are easier to answer if other people can simply copy & paste a data set to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there must better ways of doing this but this is how I would do it. Hope it is helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)


MILLION_1 <- 10^6
K_50 <- 10^4*5

# dummy data --------------------------------------------------------------------

d_1m <- 
  tibble(
    lid_1m = 1:MILLION_1,
    long_1m = abs(rnorm(MILLION_1) * 100),
    lat_1m = abs(rnorm(MILLION_1)) * 100
  )


d_50k <- 
  tibble(
    lid_50k= 1:K_50,
    long_50k = abs(rnorm(K_50) * 100),
    lat_50k = abs(rnorm(K_50) * 100)
  )


# distance calculation for each facility ------------------------------------------

future::plan(multiprocess)

d_distance <- 
  # take one row of facility: long,lat and id as an input
  future_pmap_dfr(d_50k, function(...){
  d50_row <- tibble(...)
  # to calculate distance between one facility location and 1 million other locations 
  d <- tidyr::crossing(d_1m, d50_row)
  
  d %>% 
    mutate(
      #euclidean distance
      distance = sqrt((long_1m - long_50k)^2 + (lat_1m - lat_50k)^2)
      ) %>% 
    # to get the location which is the closest to the facility
    filter(distance == min(distance))

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Would it be more efficient to do the crossing from say 1000 locations to the rather than single location? i.e. how big is the overhead cost for doing the crossing using every row. 

By the way, technical I want to calculate the distance to the nearest facility for every row of location - so I will have to flip the names from your code.